# How to Use OAuth 1.0a with Signport on Volley (OAuth 1.0 authentication OAuthConsumer.sign())

Tags: java, android

I want to use  OAUTH1.0 signpost in volley. (want to achieve authentication oauth1.0 using android studio )

Answer (score 0):

step. 1: first we have to add Volley library project (after download Volley project ,go to file->new module->add gradle project -> select downloaded volley project)

step.2:add in app build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {



        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    }
```

step.3:  create a class OAuthVolley

```
   import android.support.v4.util.LongSparseArray;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthException;

/**
 * @author (c) 2015, René de Groot available under Apache License Version 2.0
 */
public class OAuthVolley extends HurlStack
{
    private final OAuthConsumer consumer;
    private LongSparseArray<String> methods = new LongSparseArray<>();

    public OAuthVolley(OAuthConsumer consumer)
    {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }



    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try
        {





                connection.setRequestMethod(HttpPost.METHOD_NAME);
                // Could be faster by have a single consumer instance per thread and no synchronized
           //    synchronized (consumer)
                {
                    consumer.sign(connection);
                }


        }
        catch (OAuthException e)
        {
            throw new IOException("Failed to OAuth sign this Volley connection", e);
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

step.4: now create method to use volley in your MainActivity class

```
 public String POST(String url) {

            // Tag used to cancel the request
            String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
        final    OAuthConsumer dealabsConsumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(new SharedData(getApplicationContext()).getStringVar(R.string.global_key), new SharedData(getApplicationContext()).getStringVar(R.string.global_value));
         final   String accessTokenValue;


                accessTokenValue = "your_access_token";

            dealabsConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessTokenValue, new SharedData(getApplicationContext()).getStringVar(R.string.global_tkn_secret));





    RequestQueue  queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this, new OAuthVolley(dealabsConsumer)); //this line add signpost to url


                  JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d("TAG_Login", response.toString());

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("TAG_Login", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    // hide the progress dialog

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


                    return super.getParams();
                }


                @Override
                public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map headers = new HashMap();
                    headers.put("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf8");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");

                    return headers;
                }

            };

            queue.add(jsonObjReq);
        //    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

            return FResult;

        }
```

Comment: also take some idea from here-https://gist.github.com/rcgroot/64401f2608098a0bfd4e